# Chartjs Line Chart - Array of arrays for the data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using a Line Chart and Scatter Chart from Chart.js

[image]

My data is games played on Fifa. Each game is in a season and each season is in a division.

I want to slice my data by division and it works perfectly for the Scatter Chart - the data for each season can be turned on and off by the division label

For the Scatter Chart I am only showing the total points for each season, but for the Line Chart I am showing the cumulative points so each season has an array of data.

Here are the two chart's datasets when I try and put the Line Chart in the same format as the Scatter Chart: (this does not work though as the chart is blank)
[image]

Is it possible to have an array of arrays for Chart.js Line Charts?

Here is my code for the line chart:

```
const SeasonStatsLineChart = props => {
    const { matches, seasons, stat } = props;

    const theme = useTheme();

    const seasonStats = [];

    seasons.forEach((season, index) => {
        seasonStats.push({ season: season._id, division: season.division, stats: [] });

        matches.forEach(match => {
            if (match.season === season._id) {
                const matchValue = match.result === "Win" ? 3 : match.result === "Draw" ? 1 : 0;
                
                if (!seasonStats[index].stats.length) {
                    seasonStats[index].stats.push(matchValue);
                } else {
                    seasonStats[index].stats.push(seasonStats[index].stats[seasonStats[index].stats.length - 1] + matchValue);
                }
            }
        })
    })

    const divisions = [6,7,8,9,10]

    const lineChartDatasets = [];

    seasonStats.forEach(seasonStat => seasonStat.stats.unshift(0));

    divisions.forEach(division => {
        let backgroundColor;

        switch (division) {
            case 6:
                backgroundColor = "green";
                break;
            case 7:
                backgroundColor = "yellow";
                break;
            case 8:
                backgroundColor = "purple";
                break;
            case 9:
                backgroundColor = "cyan";
                break;
            default:
                backgroundColor = "red";
        }

        lineChartDatasets.push({
            label: `Div ${division}`,
            data: seasonStats.filter(season => season.division === division).map(season => season.stats),
            borderColor: backgroundColor,
            fill: false,
            pointRadius: 0.5
        })
    })

    const statRecords = []

    let count = 0;
    while (count < 11) {
        statRecords.push(count)
        count++;
    }

    return (
        <Grid item container>
            <Grid item xs={12} style={{ height: 270 }}>
                <Line
                    data={{
                        labels: statRecords,
                        datasets: lineChartDatasets

                    }}
                    options={{
                        responsive: true,
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        title: { text: `Cumulative Points per Season`, display: true },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: stat
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    precision: 0
                                }
                            }],
                            xAxes: [{
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: 'Games'
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                    }}
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default SeasonStatsLineChart;
```

Comment: So you have an array of arrays. Can you show what you have done on your dataset part of the Line chart?

Comment: @ksa Hi, I have added the code for the line chart component to show how I am getting the dataset for it. Is a line chart with an array of arrays possible do you know? Is there something obvious that's wrong?

Comment: I guess your dataset is not in the right format. The dataset takes an array of objects as input. Each object has a data field that takes only a set of arrays not an array of arrays. E.g: ```datasets: [{ 
label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
}, {
label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [70, 60, 100, 91, 58, 50, 20],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'red',
}]
``` check this link https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html